# Access is denied error while moving file using MoveFileEx on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-locking, movefileex

I am using `MoveFileEx()` API to move an existing file to a new file. I'm executing below program multiple times via a script.

Below program creates a unique file on every execution, and moves it to some file, say `FinalCAFile.txt`.
But, for some process execution, I'm getting an "**Access is denied**" error.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

#define BUFSIZE 1024

void PrintError(LPCTSTR errDesc,string process_id);


int main(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BOOL fSuccess = FALSE;

    //Get process id to create unique file
    std::string process_id = std::to_string(_getpid());

    std::string tempCaFile = "C://Users//Administrator//source//repos//MyProgram//Debug//tempCAFile" + process_id + ".txt";;
    std::string finalCaFile = "C://Users//Administrator//source//repos//MyProgram//Debug//FinalCAFile.txt";

    //Create unique temp CA file 
    std::ofstream file(tempCaFile);
    std::string my_string = "Hello from process " + process_id;
    file << my_string;

    std::wstring sourceTempCAFile = std::wstring(tempCaFile.begin(), tempCaFile.end());
    std::wstring finalCAFile = std::wstring(finalCaFile.begin(), finalCaFile.end());

    file.close();

    //move temporary created file to FinalCAFile.txt
    fSuccess = MoveFileEx(sourceTempCAFile.c_str(),
                finalCAFile.c_str(),
                MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING | MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH);
    if (!fSuccess)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"\nMoveFileEx failed for"<<process_id;
        file.close();
        PrintError(TEXT("MoveFileEx failed"),process_id);
        return (9);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl<<"\nMoveFileEx Success for " << process_id;
        std::string passedFileName = "C://Users//Administrator//source//repos//MyProgram//Debug//PassedFile" + process_id + ".txt";
        std::ofstream passedFile(passedFileName);
        std::string my_string = "Passed for process id: " + process_id;
        passedFile << my_string;
        passedFile.close();
    }

    file.close();
    return (0);
}

//  ErrorMessage support function.
//  Retrieves the system error message for the GetLastError() code.
//  Note: caller must use LocalFree() on the returned LPCTSTR buffer.
LPCTSTR ErrorMessage(DWORD error, string process_id)
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    //error = 5;
    printf("\nDWORD=%d", (unsigned int)error);
    std::string failedFileName = "C://Users//Administrator//source//repos//MyProgram//Debug//FailedFile" + process_id + ".txt";
    std::ofstream failedFile(failedFileName);
    
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        error,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL);

    std::string my_string = "Failed for process id: " + process_id + " due to " + std::to_string((unsigned int)error) ;
    failedFile << my_string;


    return((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf);
}

//  PrintError support function.
//  Simple wrapper function for error output.
void PrintError(LPCTSTR errDesc, string process_id)
{
    LPCTSTR errMsg = ErrorMessage(GetLastError(), process_id);
    _tprintf(TEXT("\n** ERROR ** %s: %s\n"), errDesc, errMsg);
    Sleep(10000);
    LocalFree((LPVOID)errMsg);
}
```

`MyScript.bat`

```
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,50) DO (
   start  C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApplication4\Debug\MyProgram.exe
)
```

As per my understanding, we get the "Access is denied" error if there is a write permission issue.

But here, in my case, I'm executing the same program multiple times, so I don't know how a permission issue comes into the picture.

So, there seems to be some synchronization issue.

Also, there may be the possibility that `MoveFileEx()` doesn't support a proper locking mechanism internally.
I doubt if there is a synchronization issue with `MoveFileEx()`, then others might also get this issue.

Any suggestion to avoid this issue?

This above script starts executing `MyProgram.exe` 50 times, and on some executions few processes are giving the "Access is denied" error.

The result is inconsistent, I don't get the error on every script run, but after 2-3 runs I'm able to get the error.

Comment: `std::wstring(tempCaFile.begin(), tempCaFile.end())` - That's not how you convert a narrow character string to a wide character string. Use [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) instead, or one of the CRT interfaces.

Comment: Or, you can use `MoveFileExA()` instead, then you don't have to convert `std::string` to `std::wstring` at all. Or, just start with `std::wstring` to begin with and don't use `std::string`. But in any case, your file path literals should be using either `/` or ```\\``` instead of `//`.

Comment: Yes we can use that , but I don't think issue is related to the suggested change .

Comment: Probably antivirus software. Try running procmon to see if anything else is accessing your files.

Comment: You could try running your application with administrative privileges / elevated process. And If you're running antivirus on the machine, it could be locking the new folder while it verifies it/adds it to its clean cache.